# Filter YouTube video feed by duration using GData

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api, gdata, gdata-api

I am using the GData API method

```
- (GDataServiceTicket *)fetchFeedWithQuery:(GDataQuery *)query
                                  delegate:(id)delegate
                         didFinishSelector:(SEL)finishedSelector;
```

to fetch YouTube videos. I am trying to filter the search feed by duration. For example, I want the feed to only return videos longer than, say, 20 minutes. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

1) You can achieve this using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) by using [videoDuration](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoDuration) = long

Your request will be something similar to "GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&videoDuration=long&key={YOUR_API_KEY}"

2) If you want finer grain search on duration you can iterate videos with [video list query](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and check [videoDuration](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration) on each.

Comment: Ok. This will work for videos > 20min. Is there a way to query videos like duration > 30min and < 40min?